# docker-entrypoint.sh not found when executed inside a container but can be read via cat and vi

Tags: docker, nginx, docker-desktop

I'm using a docker-desktop for my windows laptop to build and run an nginx-container, however I can't make it work because it always output that docker-entrypoint.sh is not found although i can read it's contents via cat and vi, Here's the files i have. Do i need additional packages to install to run docker-entrypoint or am i missing something here? Tried to search on other sites and also ask chatgpt but nothing works. Thank you!

Dockerfile

```
FROM alpine:latest
ARG BUILD_ENV=local

WORKDIR /my-project

RUN apk update && \
    apk add shadow nginx tzdata --no-cache && \
    cp /usr/share/zoneinfo/Asia/Tokyo /etc/localtime && \
    apk del tzdata && \
    rm -rf /var/cache/apk/*

COPY ["./", "./"]
COPY ["./docker/old/nginx/config/nginx.${BUILD_ENV}.conf", "/etc/nginx/nginx.conf"]
COPY ["./docker/old/nginx/scripts/docker-entrypoint.sh", "/docker-entrypoint.sh"]
RUN chmod +x /docker-entrypoint.sh

EXPOSE 80

ENTRYPOINT ["/docker-entrypoint.sh"]
```

docker-entrypoint.sh

```
#!/bin/sh

USER_ID=${UID:-1000}
GROUP_ID=${GID:-1000}

echo "starting with USER_ID: ${USER_ID}, GROUP_ID: ${GROUP_ID}..."

if [[ "${GROUP_ID}" != $(id -g nginx) ]]; then
    groupmod -g ${GROUP_ID} nginx
fi

if [[ "${USER_ID}" != $(id -u nginx) ]]; then
    usermod -u ${USER_ID} -g nginx nginx
fi

if [[ ! -d /var/tmp/nginx ]]; then
    mkdir -p /var/tmp/nginx
fi

chown -R nginx:nginx /my-project /var/tmp/nginx

if [[ $# -eq 0 ]]; then
    /usr/sbin/nginx
else
    exec "$@"
fi
```

Debugged it by removing the ENTRYPOINT ["/docker-entrypoint.sh"] so i can enter inside the nginx-container, file is there, user and permissions are 777 by root.
I also changed the line ending of that docker-entrypoint.sh to LF, but still not working

Comment: Just an update to this in case anyone had will run with the same case, this is the solution that fixed the issue.
On Dockerfile,
Before RUN chmod, add this COPY ["--chmod=0777 *.sh", "/"]|
Change ENTRYPOINT ["/docker-entrypoint.sh"] to ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/sh", "/docker-entrypoint.sh"]
ENTRYPOINT ["/docker-entrypoint.sh"] to ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/sh", "/docker-entrypoint.sh"]

Comment: Also, on docker-entrypoint.sh, add set -e after the #!/bin/sh

Comment: You say you're working on a Windows host; is it possible that the file has DOS-style CR+LF line endings?  That would cause the shebang line to be read as `#!/bin/sh\r` and that interpreter (including the stray carriage return) won't exist, causing the "not found" error.